# Eclipse Java 8 Base64 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a shared project which is using java.util.Base64 methods but eclipse always displays the error : Base64 cannot be resolved. 
My colleague who is also working on the same projet does not have this error.

*In Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs , the jdk crossed is 'jdk1.8.0_40'.*

On my colleague computer, the jdk crossed in eclipse is : jdk1.8.0_45 (I guess the problem should not come from this gap).